# Populating Form from data base values in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, populate

I have a edit profile page in which user can change his profile data.
Now in the edit user form I want to make the previous database values visible to the user
before he edits it.Ho to do that?

Comment: what have you done so far? What was your research?

Comment: I am basically a newbie and have started developing webpages using zend framework. I created an app in which users can register and the registered users can edit their profile etc.
While editing I want to populate the previous datas from the database to the edit-profile form.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stackoverflow @ArindamDawn . Now, i you could show us some of your code, we can help u.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function editAction() {
    $id = $this->_request->getParam('id');

    $articleForm = new Form_Article();
    $articleForm->setAction($this->getRequest()->getPathInfo());

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if($articleForm->isValid($_POST)) {

           // edit logic here
        }
    }
    $articleModel = new Model_Article();

    $article = $articleModel->find($id)->current();
    $articleForm->populate($article->toArray());

    $this->view->form = $articleForm;
}
```